# How to fix "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." when trying to run a python code through a bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, execution

I have a very simple python file ( like `print("Hello World")` since right now I'm just trying to learn how to work with bat files) that I want to execute with a bat file.

My bat file is like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\envs\test_for_bat\python.exe"C:\Users\W13\PycharmProjects\test_for_bat\main.py"
PAUSE
```

When my environment is a conda environment ( `C:\Users\Me\anaconda3\envs\test_for_bat\python.exe`) and the python file path is `C:\Users\W13\PycharmProjects\test_for_bat\main.py`.

When I double click my bat file the cmd prompt opens and write me the following error:
**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I don't understand what is wrong in here, the file itself works perfectly when I run it through PyCharm with the same conda environment.

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: Add a space before the quoted filename

Comment: As mentioned, the command and each parameter must be separated by a space.